# MongoDB: handling auto-incrementing model id's instead of Mongo's native ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Due to a management decision, we are using userId for the users collection, postId for the posts collection, and topicId for the topics collection, instead of '_id' for each collection as the unique identifier.

This causes a few problems getting started - one of the problems I have encountered is with upserts -

Using Mongoose, we have a schema that restricts userId to be a unique value - but when doing an update on a user model, with upsert set to *true*, MongoDB appears to only look at the ObjectIds of a collection to see if the same one exists - it doesn't check to see if a model already exists with the same userId - therefore Mongo does an insert instead of an update.

let me illustrate this with some data:

let's say the user's collection has one document:

```
{
_id:'561b0fad638e99481ab6d84a'
userId:3,
name:'foo'
}
```

we then run:

```
User.update({userId:3},{"$set":{name:'bar'},{upsert:true},function(err,resp){

if(err){

   // "errMessage": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: app42153482.users.$userId_1  dup key: { : 3 }",
}

});
```

one would think that MongoDB would find the existing document with userId:3 and udpate it, so there must be something I am doing wrong since it's giving me the duplicate key error?

Comment: This might be of interest to you. https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/

Comment: I find it odd that in this case it's trying to insert a new record, when one clearly exists already and should match the query used.

Comment: yes I find it odd as well, surely I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is

Comment: I know i ran into this same problem when i considered doing the same thing when i first moved to mongodb, but i don't think i ever solved it, i ended up finding the article i linked, and decided the route wasn't a good fit for us.

Comment: A .find() using that query finds the correct record, right?

Comment: yeah, it could be that {upsert:true} is actually looking for ObjectIds only and does not consider the condition argument for matching, that is my only current working hypothesis

Comment: yeah the object with userId:3 is there - if I delete it, the first update works, and becomes an insert but the same update will try to do another insert, thus the duplicate key error

Comment: And, i'm assuming a `.find(..., (err, inst) => {inst.name = 'bar'; inst.save();})` works? (should, because it'l use the _id instead of userId) would at least be a workaround till you find a solution.

Comment: that would probably work as a workaround yeah, let me try it

Comment: that workaround works, but would like to find out why the original problem occurs

Comment: Have you restarted and re-indexed the table since adding the unique constraint? Are there already duplicates for this field in the data?

Comment: Ok, I can not reproduce this on the shell, which leads me to the conclusion that it is not an inherent problem of MongoDB. Which in turn means that we might have an implementation problem. Since your code seems to be correct, we most likely have an implementation problem with either the node driver itself or with mongoose. I have dug through both ticket systems and can not find any ticket matching your problems. I think we have to dig into that a bit deeper. Are we talking of a sharded collection?

Comment: you forgot the closing `}` for the modifier.. maybe a typo..

Comment: I tried to replicate the same in the mongo shell, but all in vein. It is working perfect. Have you checked the Mike Brant's suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which versions of MongoDB and Mongoose you are using, but I couldn't reproduce your problem with MongoDB 3.0 and Mongoose 4.1.10.

I made a sample for you which will create and save a new user, update (using upsert) it, and create another one through an upsert. Try running this code:

```
"use strict";
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// Connect to test
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");

// Lets create your schema
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    userId: {type: Number, unique: true },
    name: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema, "Users");


User.remove() // Let's prune our collection to start clean
    .then( function() {
        // Create our sample record
        var myUser = new User({
            _id:'561b0fad638e99481ab6d84a',
            userId:3,
            name:'foo'
        });

        return myUser.save();
    })
    .then( function() {
        // Now its time to update (upsert userId 3)
        return User.update({userId:3},{"$set":{name:'bar'}},{upsert:true});
    })
    .then( function() {
        // Now its time to insert (upsert userId 4)
        return User.update({userId:4},{"$set":{name:'bee'}},{upsert:true});
    })
    .then( function() {
        // Lets show what we have inserted
        return User.find().then(function(data) {console.log(data)});
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
        // Show errors if anything goes wrong
        console.error("ERROR", err);
    })
    .then( function() {
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Typically the default value ObjectId is more ideal for the _id. Here, in this situation you can either override the default _id or you can have your own field for id(like userId in your case).

Use a separate **counters collection** to track the last number sequence used. The **_id** field contains the sequence name and the **seq** field contains the last value of the sequence.

Insert into the **counters collection**, the initial value for the userid:

```
db.counters.insert(    {
      _id: "userid",
      seq: 0    } )
```

Create a **getNextSequence** function that accepts a name of the sequence. The function uses the **findAndModify()** method to atomically increment the **seq** value and return this new value:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

Use this **getNextSequence()** function during **insert()**.

```
db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Sarah C."
   }
)

db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Bob D."
   }
)
```

This way you can maintain as many sequences as you want in the same counter collection. For the upsert issue, check out the ***Optimistic Loop*** block in this link [Create an auto-increment sequence field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

The second approach is to use a mongoose middleware like [mongodb-autoincrement](https://github.com/TheRoSS/mongodb-autoincrement).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please tell me this getNextSequence()  function you made it in mongodb(procedure) or on your server ??

Comment: @Sudhansu you can create it at the server level as a database utility function.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation (of MongoDB 3.0) upsert:true will only not insert a non-existing document if your query conditions match on the _id field.

See: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id

Why are you not using the user_name for a user as unique id?

Because auto-incrementing fields as ids are a bad practice to use in a mongodb environment, especially if you want to use sharding
=> all your inserts will occur on the latest shard
=> the mongodb cluster will have to rebalance often / redistribute the data around.
(Currently this will not occur on your system as you still use the generated _id field)

You can off course also create a unique index on the user_id field:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique

Comment: I'm not understanding why setting a user ID using a number increment is a problem for Sharding.  I thought creating a user profile happens once and setting and how we set user ID is completely unknown to the sharding system?